# Data report critique

Tags: page-layout, critique

I am designing a PowerPoint template for a data report. I am more or less happy with the layout of the elements and unity of elements, but even after a few days I still not sure about the weight of certain areas of the page. Specifically the right-hand side text box has a triangle that takes up a lot of the weight of the composition. See below:

[image]

I initially tried to diagonally align the text, and that helped a bit, but ultimately not a solution because it's not scalable: need to be able to just insert a vanilla text box, not have a new text box for each line.

### Question

Weight is just one of my personal observations, but with this post I simply aim to invite broad critique of the design.

Answer (score 2):

Before reading the question I thought that the only thing I would adjust is the right margin on the upper dark blue trapezoid's text. And actually, that is what IMHO solves partially your problem.

[image]

But you can lower the weight of that element by adding a ribbon for example.

[image]